# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir react-native run-ios

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, file-permissions

I've been getting this error when I run
`react-native run-ios`

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/vepo.app
Launching org.reactjs.native.example.vepo
org.reactjs.native.example.vepo: 6625
Benjamins-MBP:frontend Ben$ react-native run-ios
fs.js:115
    throw err;
    ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/.cache/@babel/register/.babel.7.2.2.development.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:439:3)
    at Object.writeFileSync (fs.js:1190:35)
    at save (/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:52:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

I've been getting this error when I run 
`sudo react-native run-ios`

```
/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:90
                        throw err0;
                        ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/.cache'
    at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:753:3)
    at sync (/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
    at sync (/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at sync (/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:77:24)
    at save (/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend/node_modules/@babel/register/lib/cache.js:50:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
Process terminated. Press <enter> to close the window
```

I've tried changing the permissions to read/write for those specific files in the errors and for the whole folder. What do I need to do?

**EDIT:**
I read that it can be node is not installed correctly so reinstalled node with brew. Same error.

Comment: Did you try running the command with sudo?

Comment: From within the `/Users/Ben/Development/Projects/vepo/frontend` directory, run `sudo chown -R $USER .`

Comment: @robertklep comment solved the issue. Thanks Robert. :)

Answer (score -1):

type "sudo" before your command.

```
sudo react-native run-ios
```